# Flickering with Apollo Queries

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

We use Apollo GraphQl extensively in our e-commerce website and I'm having trouble with some unwanted flickering when the route changes.

My `ProductTypeFilter` component is wrapped in a `Router` and `Query` component. The `Query` uses information from the route as its variable, in this example the `productTypeId`.

```
export const ProductTypeFilterContainer = () => (
  <Router>
    {({ query: { productTypeId } }) => (
      <Query query={GET_PRODUCT_FILTERS} variables={{ productTypeId }}>
        {({ error, loading, data: { productFilters } }) => {
          if (loading || error) {
            return null
          }
          return <ProductTypeFilter productFilters={productFilters} />
        }}
      </Query>
    )}
  </Router>
)
```

`null` is rendered for a short time and when the data arrives the `ProductTypeFilter`is rendered. This works as expected.

However, when the user navigates to a different product type, `ProductTypeFilter` will be unmounted, then remounted with the new data. For as long as the query loads, **`null` will be rendered which does introduce the unwanted "flickering"**.

This occurs only the first time the user visits a product type, when it's the second time the Apollo cache finds the same combination of `query` and `variables` and renders the `ProductTypeFilter` immediately.

I can't use `state`, since calling `setState` is not allowed in render functions. The only thing that seems to work is introducing a global variable that is used for rendering and updated when new data arrives:

```
let previousFilters = undefined

...

if (!error && previousFilters && !productFilters) {
  productFilters = previousFilters
}
if (error || productFilters) {
  return null
}

previousFilters = productFilters

return <ProductTypeFilter productFilters={productFilters} />
```

Is there a better that doesn`t give me goosebumps?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but this seems to be the intended behavior from apollo client. It caches data under the id and typename, so if you change the id in the query variables, apollo won't find it in the cache.

I feel like it could be appropriate to use a loading state here until the data comes back from the query.

If the data is already in the cache but under a different key or id, you could consider using [cache redirects](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#cacheRedirect).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apollo is going to refetch your query, set loading to true and return null each time that component is mounted.

It will do this despite the fact that (if you have Apollo cache setup) it already has the data stored in the cache.

I would suggest reordering your code like this pseudo-code below:

```
// it's a good idea to let your users know if something goes wrong
if(error) return ErrorMessage 

// note it's before loading
if(data) return ProductTypeFilter

// it's a good idea to let your users know there is some activity
if(loading) return LoadingIndicator
```

This way you will see the loading indicator or null on the first load but see the data right away if it is cached - no flashing.